# Can I invoke an instance method on a Ruby module without including it?

Tags: ruby, module, methods

#### Background:

I have a module which declares a number of instance methods

```
module UsefulThings
  def get_file; ...
  def delete_file; ...

  def format_text(x); ...
end
```

And I want to call some of these methods from within a class. How you normally do this in ruby is like this:

```
class UsefulWorker
  include UsefulThings

  def do_work
    format_text("abc")
    ...
  end
end
```

#### Problem

`include UsefulThings` brings in *all* of the methods from `UsefulThings`. In this case I only want `format_text` and explicitly do not want `get_file` and `delete_file`.

I can see several possible solutions to this:

1. Somehow invoke the method directly on the module without including it anywhere

   - I don't know how/if this can be done. (Hence this question)
2. Somehow include `Usefulthings` and only bring in some of it's methods

   - I also don't know how/if this can be done
3. Create a proxy class, include `UsefulThings` in that, then delegate `format_text` to that proxy instance

   - This would work, but anonymous proxy classes are a hack. Yuck.
4. Split up the module into 2 or more smaller modules

   - This would also work, and is probably the best solution I can think of, but I'd prefer to avoid it as I'd end up with a proliferation of dozens and dozens of modules - managing this would be burdensome

Why are there lots of unrelated functions in a single module? It's `ApplicationHelper` from a rails app, which our team has de-facto decided on as the dumping ground for anything not specific enough to belong anywhere else. Mostly standalone utility methods that get used everywhere. I could break it up into seperate helpers, but there'd be 30 of them, all with 1 method each... this seems unproductive

Comment: If you take the 4th approach (splitting up the module), you could make it so that one module always automatically includes the other by using the [`Module#included` callback](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-included) to trigger an `include` of the other. The `format_text` method could be moved into it's own module, since it seems to be useful on it's own. This would make management a little less burdensome.

Comment: I'm perplexed by all the references in the answers to module functions. Suppose you have `module UT; def add1; self+1; end; def add2; self+2; end; end` and you want to use `add1` but not `add2` in class `Fixnum`. How would it help to have module functions for that? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

If a method on a module is turned into a module function you can simply call it off of Mods as if it had been declared as

```
module Mods
  def self.foo
     puts "Mods.foo(self)"
  end
end
```

The module_function approach below will avoid breaking any classes which include all of Mods.

```
module Mods
  def foo
    puts "Mods.foo"
  end
end

class Includer
  include Mods
end

Includer.new.foo

Mods.module_eval do
  module_function(:foo)
  public :foo
end

Includer.new.foo # this would break without public :foo above

class Thing
  def bar
    Mods.foo
  end
end

Thing.new.bar
```

However, I'm curious why a set of unrelated functions are all contained within the same module in the first place?

*Edited* to show that includes still work if `public :foo` is called after `module_function :foo`

Comment: As an aside, `module_function` turns the method into a private one, which would break other code - otherwise this'd be the accepted answer

Comment: I ended up doing the decent thing and refactoring my code into seperate modules. It wasn't as bad as I thought it might be. Your answer is would still solve it most correctly WRT my original constraints, so accepted!

Comment: @dgtized related functions may end up in one module all the time, that doesn't mean that I want to pollute my namespace with all of them. A simple example if there's a `Files.truncate` and a `Strings.truncate` and I want to use both in the same class, explicitly. Creating a new class/instance each time I need a specific method or modifying the original is not a nice approach, though I'm not a Ruby dev.

Answer (score 184):

I think the shortest way to do just throw-away single call (without altering existing modules or creating new ones) would be as follows:

```
Class.new.extend(UsefulThings).get_file
```

Comment: Very usefull for files erb. html.erb, or js.erb. thanks !  I wonder if this system wastes memory

Comment: @AlbertCatalà according to my tests and http://stackoverflow.com/a/23645285/54247 the anonymous classes are garbage collected just as everything else, so it shouldn't waste memory.

Comment: If you don't like to make an anonymous class as proxy you could also use an object as proxy for the method. `Object.new.extend(UsefulThings).get_file`

Answer (score 102):

Another way to do it if you "own" the module is to use `module_function`.

```
module UsefulThings
  def a
    puts "aaay"
  end
  module_function :a

  def b
    puts "beee"
  end
end

def test
  UsefulThings.a
  UsefulThings.b # Fails!  Not a module method
end

test
```

Comment: And for the case where you don't own it:  UsefulThings.send :module_function, :b

Comment: module_function converts the method to a private one (well it does in my IRB anyway), which would break other callers :-(

Comment: I actually like this approach, for my purposes at least. Now I can call `ModuleName.method :method_name` to get a method object and call it via `method_obj.call`. Otherwise I would have to bind the method to an instance of the original object, which isn't possible if the original object is a Module. 

In response to Orion Edwards, `module_function` does make the original instance method private. http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001642

Comment: Orion - I don't believe that's true. According to http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_module.html#Module.module_function, module_function "creates module functions for the named methods. These functions may be called with the module as a receiver, and also become available as instance methods to classes that mix in the module. Module functions are copies of the original, and so may be changed independently. The instance-method versions are made private. If used with no arguments, subsequently defined methods become module functions."

Comment: One more twist: How to call `b` from inside `a`?

Comment: you could also define it as `def self.a; puts 'aaay'; end`

Comment: The private issue @OrionEdwards has can be solved by adding the line `public :a` after the *module_function* call. This is the intended behaviour of [*Module#module_function*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-i-module_function).

Answer (score 26):

If you want to call these methods without including module in another class then you need to define them as module methods:

```
module UsefulThings
  def self.get_file; ...
  def self.delete_file; ...

  def self.format_text(x); ...
end
```

and then you can call them with

```
UsefulThings.format_text("xxx")
```

or

```
UsefulThings::format_text("xxx")
```

But anyway I would recommend that you put just related methods in one module or in one class. If you have problem that you want to include just one method from module then it sounds like a bad code smell and it is not good Ruby style to put unrelated methods together.

Answer (score 22):

To invoke a module instance method without including the module (and without creating intermediary objects):

```
class UsefulWorker
  def do_work
    UsefulThings.instance_method(:format_text).bind(self).call("abc")
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Be careful with this approach: binding to self may not provide the method with everything it expects. For example, perhaps `format_text` assumes the existence of another method provided by the module, which (generally) won't be present.

Comment: This is the way , can load any module , no matter if module support method can be load directly.  Even it is better to change in Module level. But in some cases, This line is What askers want to get.

Answer (score 11):

Not sure if someone still needs it after 10 years but I solved it using eigenclass.

```rb
module UsefulThings
  def useful_thing_1
    "thing_1"
  end

  class << self
    include UsefulThings
  end
end

class A
  include UsefulThings
end

class B
  extend UsefulThings
end

UsefulThings.useful_thing_1 # => "thing_1"
A.new.useful_thing_1 # => "thing_1"
B.useful_thing_1 # => "thing_1"
```

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, I'd recommend breaking the module up into the useful things you need.  But you can always create a class extending that for your invocation:

```
module UsefulThings
  def a
    puts "aaay"
  end
  def b
    puts "beee"
  end
end

def test
  ob = Class.new.send(:include, UsefulThings).new
  ob.a
end

test
```

Answer (score 6):

A. In case you, always want to call them in a "qualified", standalone way (UsefulThings.get_file), then just make them static as others pointed out,

```
module UsefulThings
  def self.get_file; ...
  def self.delete_file; ...

  def self.format_text(x); ...

  # Or.. make all of the "static"
  class << self
     def write_file; ...
     def commit_file; ...
  end

end
```

B. If you still want to keep the mixin approach in same cases, as well the one-off standalone invocation, you can have a one-liner module that *extends* itself with the mixin:

```
module UsefulThingsMixin
  def get_file; ...
  def delete_file; ...

  def format_text(x); ...
end

module UsefulThings
  extend UsefulThingsMixin
end
```

So both works then:

```
  UsefulThings.get_file()       # one off

   class MyUser
      include UsefulThingsMixin  
      def f
         format_text             # all useful things available directly
      end
   end
```

IMHO it's cleaner than `module_function` for every single method - in case want all of them.

Comment: `extend self` is a common idiom.

Answer (score 5):

As I understand the question, you want to mix some of a module's instance methods into a class.

Let's begin by considering how [Module#include](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-include) works. Suppose we have a module `UsefulThings` that contains two instance methods:

```
module UsefulThings
  def add1
    self + 1
  end
  def add3
    self + 3
  end
end

UsefulThings.instance_methods
  #=> [:add1, :add3]
```

and `Fixnum` `include`s that module:

```
class Fixnum
  def add2
    puts "cat"
  end
  def add3
    puts "dog"
  end
  include UsefulThings
end
```

We see that:

```
Fixnum.instance_methods.select { |m| m.to_s.start_with? "add" }
  #=> [:add2, :add3, :add1] 
1.add1
2 
1.add2
cat
1.add3
dog
```

Were you expecting `UsefulThings#add3` to override `Fixnum#add3`, so that `1.add3` would return `4`? Consider this:

```
Fixnum.ancestors
  #=> [Fixnum, UsefulThings, Integer, Numeric, Comparable,
  #    Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

When the class `include`s the module, the module becomes the class' superclass. So, because of how inheritance works, sending `add3` to an instance of `Fixnum` will cause `Fixnum#add3` to be invoked, returning `dog`.

Now let's add a method `:add2` to `UsefulThings`:

```
module UsefulThings
  def add1
    self + 1
  end
  def add2
    self + 2
  end
  def add3
    self + 3
  end
end
```

We now wish `Fixnum` to `include` only the methods `add1` and `add3`. Is so doing, we expect to get the same results as above.

Suppose, as above, we execute:

```
class Fixnum
  def add2
    puts "cat"
  end
  def add3
    puts "dog"
  end
  include UsefulThings
end
```

What is the result? The unwanted method `:add2` is added to `Fixnum`, `:add1` is added and, for reasons I explained above, `:add3` is not added. So all we have to do is `undef` `:add2`. We can do that with a simple helper method:

```
module Helpers
  def self.include_some(mod, klass, *args)
    klass.send(:include, mod)
    (mod.instance_methods - args - klass.instance_methods).each do |m|
      klass.send(:undef_method, m)
    end
  end
end
```

which we invoke like this:

```
class Fixnum
  def add2
    puts "cat"
  end
  def add3
    puts "dog"
  end
  Helpers.include_some(UsefulThings, self, :add1, :add3)
end
```

Then:

```
Fixnum.instance_methods.select { |m| m.to_s.start_with? "add" }
  #=> [:add2, :add3, :add1] 
1.add1
2 
1.add2
cat
1.add3
dog
```

which is the result we want.

Answer (score 1):

After almost 9 years here's a generic solution:

```
module CreateModuleFunctions
  def self.included(base)
    base.instance_methods.each do |method|
      base.module_eval do
        module_function(method)
        public(method)
      end
    end
  end
end

RSpec.describe CreateModuleFunctions do
  context "when included into a Module" do
    it "makes the Module's methods invokable via the Module" do
      module ModuleIncluded
        def instance_method_1;end
        def instance_method_2;end

        include CreateModuleFunctions
      end

      expect { ModuleIncluded.instance_method_1 }.to_not raise_error
    end
  end
end
```

The unfortunate trick you need to apply is to include the module after the methods have been defined. Alternatively you may also include it after the context is defined as `ModuleIncluded.send(:include, CreateModuleFunctions)`.

Or you can use it via the [reflection_utils](https://github.com/thisismydesign/reflection_utils) gem.

```
spec.add_dependency "reflection_utils", ">= 0.3.0"

require 'reflection_utils'
include ReflectionUtils::CreateModuleFunctions
```

Comment: Well, your approach like the majority of responses we can see here don't address the original problem and load all the methods. The only good answer is to unbind the method from the original module and bind it in the targeted class, as @renier already responds 3 years ago.

Comment: @JoelAZEMAR I think you're misunderstanding this solution. It is to be added to the module you want to use. As a result none of its methods will have to be included in order to use them. As suggested by OP as one of possible solutions: "1, Somehow invoke the method directly on the module without including it anywhere". This is how it works.

Answer (score 1):

This old question comes to me today when I am studing Ruby and found interesting so I want to answer with my new knowlege.

Assume that you have the module

```rb
module MyModule
  def say
    'I say'
  end

  def cheer
    'I cheer'
  end
end
```

then with the class so call `Animal` I can take `cheer` method from MyModule as following

```rb
class Animal
  define_method(:happy, MyModule.method(:cheer))
end
```

This is so called unbound method, so you can take a callable object and bind it to another place(s).

From this point, you can use the method as usual, such as

```rb
my_dog = Animal.new

my_dog.happy # => "I cheer"
```

Hope this help as I also learned something new today.

To learn further, you can use `irb` and take a look at Method object.

Comment: I like this. Super useful for borrowing functionality in tests.