# Import into local scope

Tags: ruby

Consider

```
# sun.rb
class Sunshine
  def bright?
    return true
  end
end

def greeting(greeter)
  puts "hello, Sun from #{greeter}"
end


# main.rb
def abc
  my_load "sun.rb"
  greeting("abc")
  return Sunshine.new
end

s = abc
puts s.bright?
greeting("Adrian")
...
```

Can I have such a `my_load` here that the `greeting("abc")` call succeeds, but the latter `greeting("Adrian")` causes a NoMethodError; but the `puts s.bright?` call succeeds.

So, synthetically speaking: such that classes,methods from sun.rb are in the scope of the caller of `my_load` and so that they additionally get garbage collected when not referenced anymore?

Comment: That doesn't work. Methods and classes are *never* garbaged collected. It is assumed that they will be needed through the entire program, which they most likely are.

Comment: @Linuxios: Classes are objects like every other. If there is no reference to them, they get garbage collected, just like every other object. Methods are not objects in their own right, so, the idea of "garbage collecting" them makes no sense, but they are stored in classes (or modules), so their memory will be freed when the containing module gets garbage collected.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Yes, but as long as a class is referred to by it's "name" (the constant that refers to it) it will exist. And assigning to a constant is bad form and evokes a warning (which should soon become an error). So a class referred to by a constant can be considered permanent by good form. That doesn't change the fact that anything that implemented this would be a hack at best. Maybe I'll try! :).

Comment: @Linuxios: Here is a sweet, short, little program, where a class will very definitely be garbage collected: `Class.new` (Yes, that is the entire program.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I know. I get it. I mean in this situation where the class is named and assigned to a constant or declared with `class` (I love the way we programers can bicker about this).

Comment: i think it's not really relevant, but... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264930/ruby-class-object-garbage-collection

Answer (score 2):

First off, a stand-alone (called on the `main` object) method call will cause a `NameError` exception if it doesn't exist. You will get a `NoMethodError` only if you call the method on an object.

```
nothing #=> NameError
class A; end
A.nothing #=> NoMethodError
```

This is because when you call `nothing` on `main`, it doesn't know if it is a method or a variable. However:

```
nothing() #=> NoMethodError
```

Because with the `()` it now knows it is a method you are trying to call. Just something to watch out for.

Second, if you want a method to work and then not work, use `undef`.

```
def greeting(name)
   puts "Hello, #{name}"
end

greeting("Chell") #=> "Hello, Chell"
undef greeting
greeting("Chell") #=> NoMethodError
```