# Ruby include module's single method in model

Tags: ruby, methods, module, include

I have a module of following

```
module SimpleTask
    def task1
    end
    def task2
    end
    def task3
    end
end
```

And I have a model which requires only `task2` method of module `SimpleTask`.

I know including `SimpleTask` in my model with `include SimpleTask` would do the job.

But I wonder if I can only include specific `task2` method in my model.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I invoke an instance method on a Ruby module without including it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322470/can-i-invoke-an-instance-method-on-a-ruby-module-without-including-it)

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you need to refactor `#task2` into a separate module (e.g., `BaseTask`). Then you can easily include only `BaseTask` where you only need `#task2`.

```
module BaseTask
  def task2
    ...
  end
end

module SimpleTask
  include BaseTask

  def task1
    ...
  end

  def task3
    ...
  end
end
```

It's hard to help much more without a more concrete question (such as interdependence between the methods of `SimpleTask`, etc.

You *could* do some meta-programming where you `include SimpleTask` and then undefine the methods you don't want, but that's pretty ugly IMO.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the question, it's a good one and is very clear. I got to this page because I have the exact same question. I don't want to create a new module, nor do I want to include the other methods in the class namespace unnecessarily. I just want to include a single method from the module.

Answer (score 6):

You could add

```
module SimpleTask
    def task1
    end
    def task2
    end
    def task3
    end
    module_function :task2
end
```

So that you can call the method like a class method on the module as well as having it as an instance 
method in the places you *do* want all three methods, ie:

```
class Foo
   include SimpleTask
end #=> Foo.new.task2
class LessFoo
   def only_needs_the_one_method
      SimpleTask.task2
   end
end #=> LessFoo.new.only_needs_the_one_method
```

Or, if there's really no shared state in the module and you don't mind always using the module name itself, you can just declare all the methods class-level like so:

```
module SimpleTask
    def self.task1
    end
    def self.task2
    end
    def self.task3
    end
end

class Foo
   include SimpleTask # Does, more or less nothing now
   def do_something
     SimpleTask.task1
   end
end 
#=> Foo.new.task2 #=> "task2 not a method or variable in Foo"
#=> Foo.new.do_something does, however, work
class LessFoo
   def only_needs_the_one_method
      SimpleTask.task2
   end
end #=> LessFoo.new.only_needs_the_one_method works as well in this case
```

But you'd have to change all the callers in that case.

Comment: `module_function` is great as long as it's ok that all of the module instance methods are private. If you want them to be public you can use `extend self`. One has to be careful that none of the methods rely on state of the instance which includes them; in that case a class method would not work.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to steal an example from [delegate.rb](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/3c45a7899e239e7ece3c778d9f71e3be85fdfbed/lib/delegate.rb#L39), it restricts what it includes

```
...
class Delegator < BasicObject
  kernel = ::Kernel.dup
  kernel.class_eval do
    [:to_s,:inspect,:=~,:!~,:===,:<=>,:eql?,:hash].each do |m|
      undef_method m
    end
  end
  include kernel
...
```

becomes

```
module PreciseInclude

  def include_except(mod, *except)
    the_module = mod.dup
    the_module.class_eval do
      except.each do |m|
        remove_method m # was undef_method, that prevents parent calls
      end
    end
    include the_module
  end
end

class Foo
  extend PreciseInclude

  include_except(SimpleTask, :task1, :task2)
end

Foo.instance_methods.grep(/task/) => [:task3]
```

you can always flip it so instead of include it becomes `include_only`

The catch is that remove_method won't work for nested modules, and using undef will prevent searching the entire hierarchy for that method.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution for this is

`define_method :task2, SimpleTask.instance_method(:task2)`