# Is it possible to explicitly include sub-modules or classes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to be able to statically analyze my code. That is, to know from the plain text of the file where every function and variable comes from. IDEs and text editor plugins work better when they can trace the origin of every symbol as well.

So for example, if I have application code like this:

```ruby
#...
Y.some_method()
#...
```

Then I want to see `Y` in an include/import/require/extend/def statement somewhere on the page.

In other languages I use, one can explicitly choose which sub-parts of a namespace to bring in to the current context.

**Python:**

```python
from X import Y
```

**Haskell:**

```haskell
import X (Y)
```

**Elixir:**

```elixir
alias X.Y, as: Y
```

And while it's possible to import all contained names in Python, the "wildcard import" [is frowned upon](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

```python
from X import *
```

> ". . . they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools."

In Ruby, it seems that this fully implicit "wildcard" way is the *only* way to bring in a contained name:

```ruby
include X
```

This makes `Y` available, but is there some way to make this explicit? The [docs for Ruby `include`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-include) don't show any options.

What I'd really like to do in Ruby is something like one of these:

```
from X include Y
include X::Y as Y
```

The best I've come up with so far is:

```ruby
require 'x/y' ; Y = X::Y
```

Here's [a crazy hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20982523/106906) in the answer to another question which would enable this.

Comment: You're asking a lot of Ruby here. Every language has their own style, and Ruby's always leaned towards convenience over formality. Since Ruby has a single global namespace that every bit of code contributes to it's not always practical nor necessary to identify where something came from. The *When in Rome* principle applies here: Just do it the Ruby way when you're doing Ruby. In Python or Node.js do it their way. Going against the grain is how you create awkward, unmaintainable code, like some bizarre dialect of Ruby that behaves like Python.

Comment: @tadman What do you do, then, when you see a symbol which looks like a method call, and you want to modify it. In my case it was `log(...)`. It might have been a method of mine included, it could have been a standard library thing, it could have been from some gem... I was coming back to old code, and I decided to remove all `include` stmts so I'd at least know where code is coming from. ?

Comment: @Dogweather: You can just ask Ruby: `method(:log).owner`. By the way, you seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding about what `include` does. In particular, you seem to think that it is part of some module system. It is not. It is part of Ruby's mixin system. In other words, all that `class C; include M end` does, is make `M` `C`'s superclass.

Comment: @tadman Also, I don't see concretely how Python's admonition against wildcard imports doesn't also apply to Ruby: ". . . they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools."  (?) https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports Is it possible that in the Ruby world, we're rationalizing the lack of an explicit-import feature, saying it's not necessary?

Comment: I'm saying that the Ruby world has taken a certain approach, developed a particular philosophy, and a lot of code depends on those expectations being met. When you `require` something it's inviting that code to do whatever it deems necessary to the global namespace. In Python, like others, you have significantly more control over that. If you were to somehow restrict Ruby, or presume it *was* restricted, you're going to break tons of code and make it a lot harder to get things done.

Comment: @JörgWMittag So as a practical matter, to truly determine what some unknown `Y` is, you'd add a debugging line in the editor like `binding.pry`, switch to a terminal, start up the app, navigate to that point in the code, then work in the debugger a bit, then go back and remove the debug line? I find that a lot of work just to learn what text in the editor means.

Comment: In thinking some more about this the only way I can see this working is if Ruby supported multiple root namespaces, and these namespaces could transparently inherit from a parent. When issuing a `require` you could sandbox it to some virtual root, then pick which of the declared constants you want to import. As far as the imported code is concerned it would be in the root space, even though it wasn't contain. Note that this won't prevent code from modifying existing classes, it would just prevent them from creating new constants. That would be useful when trying to contain unruly code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. But I agree with @tadman that you should consider doing it in the Ruby way.

```
Object.define_singleton_method(:include) do |*mths, from: nil|
  mod = from || mths.first
  mod = mod.dup

  if from
     all_mths = mod.instance_methods
     (all_mths - mths).each { |mth| mod.send :undef_method, mth }
  end

  super(mod)
end

module Foobar
  def foo
    puts :foo
  end

  def bar
    puts :bar
  end
end

class Abc
  include Foobar
end

Abc.new.foo # => 'foo'
Abc.new.bar # => 'foo'

class AbcWithoutBar
  include :foo, from: Foobar
end

AbcWithoutBar.new.foo # => 'foo'
AbcWithoutBar.new.bar # => NoMethodError
```

Comment: That's very cool. I've been playing with ways to do that, calling the method `import`, in order to leave `include` alone.

Comment: @Dogweather that's a better idea than overriding `include` imho

Answer (score 2):

Ruby always executes the code that you `require`

And since there is no partial execution of a file there cannot be partial `require`.

When you `require` a feature Ruby locates the corresponding file using the load paths in `$:` and then double checks against the list of loaded files in `$"` and if the file has not yet been loaded executes the file.

Ruby is a dynamic language, the best way to reason about its source code is halting a running program rather than statically. In fact even `class` and `def` are not declarations but just method calls that are executed at runtime. Consider for example this contrived example

```
class Surprise < [Array, Hash, Fixnum, Object].sample
end
```

If you want to know where a method or class has been defined best use `pry`. You can require `pry` and then use `binding.pry` to stop anywhere in your source code and spelunk around to inspect objects and source code. Two of the most useful commands are `ls` and `$`

- `ls` prints all methods of an object or class
- `$` prints the file location and source code of a method

Comment: What i'd like is a partial `include`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `$`

Comment: Maybe look into "refinements" then. They are lexically scope includes.