# How do you invoke ruby module methods via reflection?

Tags: ruby, reflection, ruby-1.8

I'd like to get the following to work. The idea is that I can add methods to Routes and if they exist I can use them later. I'm using Ruby 1.8.

```
module Routes
  def home
    #stuff
  end

  def work
    #end
  end
end

Routes.method_defined? :home
# true

Routes.send(:home)
#NoMethodError: undefined method `home' for Routes:Module
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm missing something about how these aren't class methods but instead instance methods of the module's class? I'm just confused.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I invoke an instance method on a Ruby module without including it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322470/can-i-invoke-an-instance-method-on-a-ruby-module-without-including-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the following code you could do it:

```
Class.new.extend(Routes).send(:home)
```

Comment: I actually don't want this behavior but reading the docs it's the only way unless I turn them into module methods. The way I have them are instance methods.

Comment: I got another question, how can I tell if a module method is defined?

Comment: You've checked that before in the OP, haven't you? :)

Comment: I didn't understand the docs until I read the question you posted. =)

Comment: To answer my own followup question `Routes.respond_to?` will work nicely.